# Can I disable a specialization of std::char_traits based on a boolean expression?

Tags: c++11, template-specialization, sfinae

Using C++11 (or C++14), I'd like to specialize `std::char_traits` for `unsigned char`, but only if `!std::is_same<char, unsigned char>::value`.  (Since `std::char_traits<char>` already exists.)

So I currently have such a specialization, which begins like this:

```
namespace std {
template<>
struct char_traits<unsigned char> {
    using char_type = unsigned char;
    etc...
```

The question is if there is a way I can make this specialization "not exist" via SFINAE if `std::is_same<char, unsigned char>::value`.  All the examples I can find for enabling/disabling specializations depend on the non-specialized template having a dummy template parameter for enabling.  I obviously can't change `std::char_traits` in this way.  Is there a path I am missing?

Comment: 1) `char` and `unsigned char` are always distinct types, even if `char` is unsigned. 2) I don't think `char_traits` is exempt from the "user specializations must depend on a user-defined type" rule

Comment: T.C.: 1) Good point.  That should obviate my need.  2) Ugh.  I see that in the standard.  So specializing `uint8_t` is technically prohibited?  (I use `static_assert` to ensure that `uint8_t` is an `unsigned char`.)